# Staging Website is Empty

Tags: store-view, ee-1.12, staging

I'm attempting to create a staging environment using Magento "Staging Website" feature that was include in 1.12 (System > Content Staging).  However, after the initial set up is complete, all I'm left with is a new store view and a few empty files

```
staging/base_staging/.htaccess
staging/base_staging/index.php
```

I don't see anything in `var/log` and have reindexed.  My guess is that if these files are empty, it's obviously not going to do anything.

What could have prevented this from running correctly?

Comment: Have you checked your permissions of the _staging_ folder?  Also, when you go to the URL, does anything happen (authentication requests, etc.)?

Comment: 777 and owned by apache.  It loads fine, it's just a blank index.php so there's nothing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Enterprise_Staging_Model_Entry`

```
    /**
     * Create entry point if possible
     *
     * @return Enterprise_Staging_Model_Entry
     */
    public function save()
    {
        $this->_ensureWebsite();
        if ($this->canEntryPointBeCreated()) {
            $sample = file_get_contents(BP . DS . 'index.php.sample');
            $outputFile = $this->getFilename();
            if (!is_dir(dirname($outputFile))) {
                mkdir(dirname($outputFile));
            }
            $result = str_replace(
                array('include $', 'app/Mage.php'),
                array('include \'../../\' . $', '../../app/Mage.php'),
                $sample
            );
            $result = preg_replace('/Mage::run\(.*?\)/us', "Mage::run('{$this->_website->getCode()}', 'website')", $result);
            file_put_contents($outputFile, $result);

            $sample = file_get_contents(BP . DS . '.htaccess.sample');

$search = <<<SEARCH
############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment
SEARCH;

$replace = <<<REPLACE
############################################
## add 'no_cache' GET parameter for staging sites

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|[?&])no_cache([&=]|$)
    RewriteRule (.*) $1?no_cache [QSA]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment
REPLACE;

            $sample = str_replace($search, $replace, $sample);
            $outputFile = $this->getBaseFolder() . DS . $this->_website->getCode() . DS . '.htaccess';
            file_put_contents($outputFile, $sample);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Make sure `index.php.sample` and `.htaccess.sample` exist.  They are copied when creating a new staging environment.